# (9600 N,8,1)--> Serial Port --> Network --> Serial Port -->(9600 N81)

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtualization, socat

how to achieve serial over IP and vice versa.

i heard it is possible doing it with SOCAT
(9600 N,8,1)--> Serial Port --> Network --> Serial Port -->(9600 N81)

requesting people to help me on this

Comment: this i have complted using SOCAT : ref link: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-ttyovertcp.txt

Answer (score 0):

[have a look at remserial](http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/) - source code is available and it seems pretty simple to use or modify.